# MFC Icon has not changes

Tags: c++, mfc

I customized an Icon resource and wrote the following sentences in the `BOOL CApplicationApp::InitInstance()` function:

```
HICON hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDI_MY_ICON);
m_pMainWnd->SetIcon(hIcon, TRUE);
m_pMainWnd->SetIcon(hIcon, FALSE);
```

but the icon has not changed, I don’t know if I wrote something wrong

Comment: The value of IDI_MY_ICON is the smallest one in the Icon folder

Comment: Is the respective icon resource linked into the executable image? How have you verified that the icon didn't change?